# How do i send CSV per CURL --compressed to an fcgi form?

Tags: csv, curl

So the partner would like to get this data to his fcgi form:

```
curl --compressed -d 'domain=somedomain' 
                  -d 'kennung=somename' 
                  -d 'passwort=XXXXX' 
                  -d 'idformular=12345' \
                  -d 'something=43' 
                  -b 'somedate=2021-01-12' 
                  -d 'otherdate=' \
```

I do have a nice little happy csv, but no idea how to get the data into that format. What i have:

```
$fp=fopen(mycsv.csv,'r');
while(!feof($fp)){
    list($...,$..., . . .) = fgetcsv($fp);
    $data=array(
        'domain'=>'somedomain',
        'kennung'=>'somename',
        ...etc
    );
    $encoded = '';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $encoded .= urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value).'&';
    }
    echo $encoded;
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "identity");
    here other stuff 4 the curl
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
}
fclose($fp);
```

What i do not understand is
the -d?
[Here the manual](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-d)
What is with the backslashes? 
Why compressed? Or is this enough?
Thanks a lot for any links, tips.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "identity");
```

Answer (score 0):

closing. code worked as is. I just messed up the PW.
So the code from partner is a bash code, but i am programming this as a triggered PHP answer (fcgi form).

Thanks Boris for the edit - pointing this fact out!

fazit:
backslashes are from partner cause he just sent me some copy past bash text

-d is for data, man already linked in post